# How to add opportunity owner in email template?

Tags: email, email-template, opportunity, owner, template

guys I am having trouble including the opportunity owner in my email template.
This is what I used to include the opportunity owner:

```
{!Opportunity.Owner}
```

But when I use this I just get a blank in my email. 
How can I include the opportunity owner in my email template.

Comment: `Opportunity.Owner` represents the relationship to a `User`, not any field in `User`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Owner field in an Email Template you have a few options of what to display in the email. If you would like to show the full name of the owner. You would need to use `{!Opportunity.OwnerFullName}`. Using just the first name would be `{!Opportunity.OwnerFirstName}` etc. This can be done with Last Name, ID, email and title as well.

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you so much. I don't understand why mine didn't work...odd. But thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome, please mark my answer as the best answer so that other users can quickly see that this solved the issue.

Comment: Yes I will def.